# Bug with cutting shapes?

Tags: inkscape, shapes

I just recognized a big bug. Could someone please confirm or give me a hint?

When cutting a shape with another shape and repasting the shape back, so both shapes lie beside each other, a small space between the shapes still exists.

I expected no space between the shapes. This is catastrophic if you paint the shapes in another program and you see the small space between them!

Could someone confirm this behavior?

Comment: As DA01 said... You can also just adjust the position of the pasted shape. Not catastrophic at all.

Comment: When you zoom in, does the space also widen? If not, it's probably not a real gap, but simply an artifact of the imperfect rendering of [coincident edges](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13413) in vector graphics.

Answer (score 3):

Could you provide a step-by-step process? Normally pasting does not preserve the objects location on the pasteboard...so there's a natural shift. What I often do is duplicate the 'cutting' shape and cut with that, leaving the original shape in the exact same position.

Comment: Only now I see, that you already gave this answer (+1), I too much concentrated on the counter-question *`Could you provide a step-by-step process?`* and with checking if this "bug" exists in Inkscape 0.91

Answer (score 0):

**Not a bug, but a feature:** if you paste a shape from the clipboard, it's placed just where your mouse cursor is. As to "paste" the cutting shape back, duplicate it, then cut the duplicate from the other shape:

Try the following steps:

- draw a rectangle (remove the stroke)
- Ctrl+C
- Ctrl+V after moving the mouse a little in x and y direction from the centre
- Ctrl+D duplicates copied shape (switches selection to new shape)
- Ctrl+Leftclick first shape (adds it to selection)
- Ctrl+- (minus key) to cut the duplicated shape from the first shape

The little gap that may show is only a rendering artefact. I tried this with Inkscape 0.91.